# Oracle database configuration

Tags: oracle12c

I recently installed Oracle 12c for windows, I didn't get EM url to locate my host I just want to know if it's possible to locate the url manually from a file or from command prompt?

Comment: Locate the install/setupinfo.txt  file and check what's in there.

Comment: Thanks a lot managed to find it.